# Howto: if argument is numerical ... else

Tags: macros, conditionals, optional-arguments

I'm trying to create a differentiation command. At the moment I have the following:

```
\newcommand{\diff}[1][]{%
  \def\ArgI{{#1}}%
  \diffRelay%
}
\newcommand{\diffRelay}[2][]{%
  \frac{\textnormal{d}^{#1}\ArgI}{\textnormal{d}#2^{#1}}%
}
```

This allows me to use it like *\diff{x}, diff[y]{x}, diff[y][2]{x}* to create diff-by-x, diff-y-by-x, second-derivative-of-y-by-x. To simply write the n-th derivative of anything I have to use *\diff[][n]{x}*.

What I'm looking for is a way to check if the first optional argument is numerical, so I can omit the empty argument to create n-th derivative:

```
\newcommand{\diff}[1][]{%
  \def\ArgI{{#1}}%
  \diffRelay%
}
\newcommand{\diffRelay}[2][]{%
  \if \ArgI is numerical % better: \and #1 is empty
    \frac{\textnormal{d}^{\ArgI}}{\textnormal{d}#2^{\ArgI}}%
  \else
    \frac{\textnormal{d}^{#1}\ArgI}{\textnormal{d}#2^{#1}}%
}
```

Comment: how do you define "numerical"  you can test for digits, but the example you actually give is `n` which is perhaps harder to distinguish from `x` in general, unless that was a meta-example...

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like this (which actually tests for a sequence of digits resulting in >0 so don't use `[000]` ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\diff}[1][]{%
  \def\ArgI{#1}%
  \diffRelay%
}
\def\eatrelax#1\relax{}
\newcommand{\diffRelay}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\eatrelax\ifnum0=0\ArgI\relax% is numerical % better: \and #1 is empty
    \frac{\textnormal{d}^{#1}\ArgI}{\textnormal{d}#2^{#1}}%
  \else\relax
    \frac{\textnormal{d}^{\ArgI}}{\textnormal{d}#2^{\ArgI}}%
 \fi
}

\begin{document}

$\diff[2]{x}$

$\diff[y]{x}$

$\diff[y][2]{x}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: While I decided to answer the question as asked, I'd agree with egreg that using a different input syntax would be better.

Comment: I did not understand **\ifnum0=0**. Can you explain about that?

Comment: @SayOL if `\argI` is say 2 then `\ifnum0=0\argI` is `\ifnum0=02..` which is false. If `\argI` is `X` then  `\ifnum0=0\argI` is `\ifnum0=0X..` which will test true and expand to X...  In both cases you don't really want whatever you get but the `\eatrelax` cleans up afterwards.

Comment: I understand that part now. But in the definition of \eatrelax, why is it required to add open and close curly braces?

Comment: @SayOL that is the syntax of `\def` you have to put the replacement text (nothing here) between `{..}` same as `\newcommand\foo[1]{}` but the site doesn't really support multiple questions in comments, feel free to construct a new question if you have a question:-)

Comment: I finally understand it. I misunderstood the feature of \def. I just tested your  \eatrelax. I got an error when I used \eatrelax{argument}. Actually, the right usage is \eatrelax argument\relax :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the test for numeric, in my opinion. I suggest a different syntax:

```
\der[<function>]{<variable>}[<order>]
```

with two optional arguments; if you omit the first, you get the operator, otherwise the derivative; the second argument is the order of derivation.

With `xparse` it's easy to do it; the first optional argument has empty default value, whereas we use the `\IfNoValueTF` test for the second one, in order to avoid an empty superscript which would add an unwanted `\scriptspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\der}{O{}mo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}
    {\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#3}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2^{#3}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\der[y]{x}\quad
\der[y]{x}[2]\quad
\der[y]{x}[n]\quad
\der{x}\quad
\der{x}[2]\quad
\der{x}[n]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]