# A macro for typesetting sequence with flexible starting index

Tags: math-mode, macros

How can I define a new command called `\seq[StartIndex]{Base}{EndIndex}` with the following functionalities

```
\seq{a}{n}    % -> a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n
\seq[3]{a}{n} % -> a_3,a_4,\dots,a_n
\seq[k]{a}{n} % -> a_k,a_{k+1},\dots,a_n
```

Comment: would it be acceptable to use `\seq*` in the case of `k`?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend something more like `\seq[a]{1,2,n}`

Comment: Did you mean **\seq*[k]{a}{n}**?

Comment: Yes (………filler text)

Comment: @SeanAllred: yes, that is pretty fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regular expression match we can decide whether an argument only consists of digits and act of consequence.

An extended syntax featuring “open ended” sequences and subsequences is provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\seq}{O{1}omm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   { \sayol_seq:nnn {#1} {#3} {#4} }
   { \sayol_seq:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sayol_seq:nnn
 {
  #2\sb{#1},
  #2\sb
   {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A\d*\Z } { #1 }
     { \int_to_arabic:n { #1 + 1 } }
     { #1 + 1 }
   }
  ,
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #3 } { * }
   { \dotsc } 
   { \dots,#2\sb{#3} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sayol_seq:nnnn
 {
  #3\sb{#1\sb{#2}},
  #3\sb{#1\sb
   {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A\d*\Z } { #2 }
     { \int_to_arabic:n { #2 + 1 } }
     { #2 + 1 }
   }}
  ,
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #3 } { * }
   { \dotsc } 
   { \dots,#3{\sb{#1\sb{#4}}} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verb!\seq{a}{n}! produces $\seq{a}{n}$

\verb!\seq{a}{*}! produces $\seq{a}{*}$

\verb!\seq[k][1]{a}{n}! produces $\seq[k][1]{a}{n}$

\verb!\seq[k][r]{a}{n}! produces $\seq[k][r]{a}{n}$

\verb!\seq[3]{a}{n}! produces $\seq[3]{a}{n}$

\verb!\seq[k]{a}{m}! produces $\seq[k]{a}{m}$

\verb!\seq[l]{b}{m}! produces $\seq[l]{b}{m}$

\verb!\seq[l]{b}{*}! produces $\seq[l]{b}{*}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For example how could I write the factorial sequence? 1,1,2,...,n!,... or the powers of 2? 1,2,4,...,2^n,...

Comment: @SophiaAntipolis That's a very different request.

Comment: Maybe you could ask the question and self-answer, egreg ;-)

Comment: The package `l3regex` should no longer be loaded with recent TeX distributions.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \sayol_seq_typeset:nnnn
  { {#1}\sb{#2}, {#1}\sb{#3}, \dots, {#1}\sb{#4} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sayol_seq_typeset:nnnn { nnfn }

\cs_new:Nn \sayol_seq_calc:nnn % a 1 n
  { \sayol_seq_typeset:nnfn {#1} {#2} { \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } } {#3} }

\NewDocumentCommand \seq { s O{1} m O{n} }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \sayol_seq_typeset:nnnn {#3} {#2} {#2+1} {#4} }
      { \sayol_seq_calc:nnn {#3} {#2} {#4} }
  }

%%%%% alt syntax

\clist_new:N \l__sayol_tmp_clist
\int_new:N \l__sayol_tmp_int
\cs_new:Nn \sayol_seq_multi:nn
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l__sayol_tmp_clist {#2}
    \int_zero:N \l__sayol_tmp_int
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__sayol_tmp_clist
      {
        \int_incr:N \l__sayol_tmp_int
        \int_compare:nNnTF
          { \clist_count:N \l__sayol_tmp_clist }
          =
          { \l__sayol_tmp_int }
          { \dots, {#1}\sb{##1} }
          { {#1}\sb{##1}, }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \Seq { O{a} m }
  { \sayol_seq_multi:nn {#1} {#2} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[ \seq{a}[n]     \] % -> a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n
\[ \seq[3]{a}[n]  \] % -> a_3,a_4,\dots,a_n
\[ \seq*[k]{a}[n] \] % -> a_k,a_{k+1},\dots,a_n
\[ \Seq{1,2,n}    \] % -> a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n
\[ \Seq[b]{1,2,5,n}    \] % -> a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Related: https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/221

Comment: How about your recommendation \seq[a]{1,2,n}? I understood that you referred to if we use \seq{1,2,n}, it will produce 1,2,...,n

Comment: @SayOL That one is implemented in `\Seq`

Comment: Then what about `a_{k_1},a_{k_2},\dots,a_{k_n}`? It will turn up eventually ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As requested:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\seq[1][1]{%
  \def\ArgI{#1}%
  \seqt%
}
\def\eatrelax#1\relax{}
\newcommand\seqt[3][1]{%
   \expandafter\eatrelax\ifnum0=0\ArgI\relax%
    #2_{\ArgI},#2_{\ArgI+1},\ldots,#2_#3
  \else\relax
    #2_{\ArgI},#2_{\the\numexpr\ArgI+1\relax},\ldots,#2_#3
 \fi
}

\begin{document}

\verb!\seq{a}{n}! produces $\seq{a}{n}$

\verb!\seq[3]{a}{n}! produces $\seq[3]{a}{n}$

\verb!\seq[k]{a}{m}! produces $\seq[k]{a}{m}$

\verb!\seq[l]{b}{m}! produces $\seq[l]{b}{m}$

\end{document}
```

I used a variation on [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245508/3954) to [Howto: if argument is numerical ... else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245501/3954).

Comment: What did you mean by **\ifnum0=0**?

Comment: @SayOL, that is not what it reads, it says `\ifnum0=0\ArgI\relax`, thus the test is false if `\ArgI` (which is expected to be an integer) is non-empty (and not 0). `\relax` is just there for the parser to stop looking for stuff for the comparison.