Fast way to test if an argument is an integer in LaTeX3?
In the latest version of LaTeX3, what would be the fastest way to test if an argument is a string representing an integer (without LuaTex)?
Basically, I am looking for a function that would do the equivalent of the following but more lightweight because I guess that calling a regex every single time in a TeX engine might cause performance issues (but I may be mistaken).
\documentclass[varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\isinteger}{>{\TrimSpaces} m m m}{
    \is_integer:eTF{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\regex_new:N \is_integer_regex 
\regex_set:Nn \is_integer_regex{\A\s*[\+\-]?[\d]+\s*\Z}
\cs_new:Nn \is_integer:nTF{
    \regex_match:NnTF \is_integer_regex{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \is_integer:nTF{eTF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\isinteger{abcde}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{123}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{document}

QUESTION: How to achieve this in a faster way regarding compiling speed?

at a minimum, you could pre-compile the regex. off-topic but is probably isn't the best for uniqueness, module-name-wise.

@cfr the regex is precompiled, isn't it?

Some other solutions you could benchmark: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427557/how-to-test-if-an-expl3-function-argument-is-an-integer-expression?rq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50111/how-to-check-if-the-value-of-a-parameter-is-a-number, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/testing-for-number, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138737/test-whether-passed-parameter-is-a-number-possibly-floating-point-or-dimension, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245501/howto-if-argument-is-numerical-else, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167369/

The following is evil expl3 code (because it uses two happy :D macros) that implements the check for your regular expression in a pretty fast way. One could turn it even faster by implementing the \__vincent_trim_signs:n function with more lowlevel code, though I guess that's not necessary. Also, it deviates from your regular expression as it allows arbitrary many signs (just like TeX does).
To give a rough estimate, the function is roughly 36 times faster than you regex implementation on the two test cases in your MWE.
\documentclass[varwidth = true]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \vincent_if_is_int:n #1 { TF, T, F }
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__vincent_if_is_int_auxi:n
      { \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \__vincent_trim_signs:n }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__vincent_if_is_int_auxi:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \prg_return_false: }
      {
        \group_begin:
          \tex_afterassignment:D \__vincent_if_is_int_auxii:w
          \if_false: { \fi:
          \tex_count:D \c_zero_int = 0 #1
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__vincent_if_is_int_auxii:w
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__vincent_if_is_int_auxii:n \exp_after:wN { \if_false: } \fi:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__vincent_if_is_int_auxii:n #1
  {
    \group_end:
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} \prg_return_true: \prg_return_false:
  }
% strip away all leading signs
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_trim_signs:n #1
  {
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
      { \tl_if_head_eq_charcode_p:nN {#1} {+} }
      { \tl_if_head_eq_charcode_p:nN {#1} {-} }
      { \exp_args:Ne \__vincent_trim_signs:n { \tl_tail:n {#1} } }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\isinteger}{>{\TrimSpaces} m m m}{
  \vincent_if_is_int:eTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \vincent_if_is_int:n { e } { TF, T, F }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\isinteger{abcde}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{123}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{++}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{document}


This is an expandable (and non-evil) variant to check for an integer. I made the following behavioural changes:

don't trim spaces in \vincent_if_in_int:nTF (was unclean in above's code version, imho, and should only be covered by a document level command if you want this)
Don't use the >{\TrimSpaces} processor (not available in expandable commands), instead use \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN

A word of warning: Both this code and the unexpandable version above are not completely robust: They'll fail if the input contains unbalanced \if tests. If you need robustness against that the most robust approach would be to either stringify the input (so that valid input is only a literal string of numbers and leading signs), or to step through the input one token at a time and evaluating it (which might still be fragile).
\documentclass[varwidth = true]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vincent_if_is_int:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  { \exp_args:Ne \__vincent_if_is_int_aux:n { \__vincent_trim_signs:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_if_is_int_aux:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_empty:fTF
      {
        \if_int_compare:w 1 < 1#1\exp_stop_f:
        \else:
          \exp_after:wN f
        \fi:
      }
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { f } { TF }

% strip away all leading signs
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_trim_signs:n #1
  {
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF
      { \tl_if_head_eq_charcode_p:nN {#1} {-} }
      { \tl_if_head_eq_charcode_p:nN {#1} {+} }
      { \exp_args:Ne \__vincent_trim_signs:n { \tl_tail:n {#1} } }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\isinteger}{m m m}
  {
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN \vincent_if_is_int:eTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \vincent_if_is_int:n { e } { TF, T, F, p }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\isinteger{abcde}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{123}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{++}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{document}


\isinteger{++}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\isinteger{}{TRUE}{FALSE}

@yannisl point, will be fixed.

\__vincent_if_is_int_auxi:n should be protected. Why not providing also the T and F forms?

@egreg you're right, that one slipped through. Because the T and F forms aren't necessary for this MWE, but yes, I can add them for completeness.

Skillmon: how would you do it in an expandable way?

@Vincent the most robust solution I have found for this is stepping through the string token by token and running an expandable if-digit test.

@Vincent If it doesn't have to be as robust you can use a \ifnum1<1#1 based test.

@Vincent I added an expandable version.

@Skillmon Why do you mark the aux function in the expandable version protected? I thought protection was preventing expansion.

@Vincent oversight on my end :) Well spotted will be fixed.

@Skillmon At least I feel that I'm starting to improve my skills and understand the general logic ;)
